# MySQL query add duration to previous record

Tags: mysql, sql, time, sql-update, duration

I like to add event duration to a previous record every time a new record gets added.

This is what I have

```
ID EventType EventTime EventDuration
-------------------------------------
1  TypeA     10:20     NULL
2  TypeB     09:30     NULL
3  TypeC     08:00     NULL
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
ID EventType EventTime EventDuration
-------------------------------------
1  TypeA     10:20     00:50
2  TypeB     09:30     01:30
3  TypeC     08:00     ...
4  ...       ...
```

When a new records gets added (with ID, EventType and EventTime), the duration of the previous record (timediff between TypeB and Type A) should be added to the previous record in column EventDuration.

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT 
   id, EventTime,
   timestampdiff(minute,
      (SELECT EventTime 
       FROM TableName t2
       WHERE t2.id < t1.id ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1),EventTime) 
       AS EventDuration
       FROM records t1
       WHERE id = ....<this is where I get stuck, this should be a query that identifies the ID of latest EventTime record>
```

Any suggestions?

(I am running MySQL 5.6.39)

Comment: How does 08:00 - 09:30 come out as 00:30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select id, timediff(eventTime, lag(eventTime) over(order by eventTime)) event_duration
    from mytable t
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.event_duration = t1.event_duration
```

If you want to update only the last but 1 record, you can `order by` and `limit` in the subquery (or in the outer query):

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select id, timediff(eventTime, lag(eventTime) over(order by eventTime)) event_duration
    from mytable t
    order by id desc
    limit 1, 1
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.event_duration = t1.event_duration
```

---

In earlier versions, one option is to emulate `lag()` with a window function:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select 
        id, 
        timediff(
            (select min(eventTime) from mytable t1 where t1.eventTime > t.eventTime),
            eventTime
        ) event_duration
    from mytable t
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.event_duration = t1.event_duration
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just found out I am running MySQL 5.6.39 and seems some of these functions are not available (e.g. LAG, OVER)

Comment: @Ant: ok. I edited my answer with a solution for earlier versions of MySQL.

Comment: Great, this works! Thanks so much! Small question, it seems all the rows get updated, which might slow things down in larger tables? Would there be a way to add a LIMIT 1 or something similar? So that ONLY the previous record gets updated?

Comment: Actually I found that it gets updated to the wrong row. The outcome (duration) should be one below. Or in other words, the TIMEDIFF comparison is between the wrong rows (should be shifted one up). This is the outcome I get: https://imgur.com/FHGEGIC

Comment: @Ant: I think I see what you mean. I updated the last query in my answer accordingly.

Comment: I came to realise that it is better practice to request the output of the query, rather than update this in a column. I have been trying to convert this to a query, but without success. Any suggestions / hints?